# ServiceStack: Error calling service

Tags: compiler-errors, servicestack

I have implemented the a ServiceStack sample service, just like in the documentation - github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Create-your-first-webservice

The problem is that when I try calling it I get these errors:

```
"cannot convert from 'string' to 'ServiceStack.ServiceHost.IReturnVoid'"
```

and

```
The best overloaded method match for 'ServiceStack.ServiceClient.Web.ServiceClientBase.Get(ServiceStack.ServiceHost.IReturnVoid)' has some invalid arguments
```

My code for calling the service:

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient("http://host:8080/");
HelloResponse response = client.Get(new Hello { Name = "World!" });
```

Can anyone help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HelloResponse response = client.Get<string>(new Hello { Name = "World!" });
```

you have to specify the return type in generic methods like these.

Comment: Ok, I tried this and it worked:
`HelloResponse response = client.Get<HelloResponse>("/hello/World!");`

but then I tried this:
`HelloResponse response = client.Get<HelloResponse>(new Hello{Name = "John"});`

and I got this error:
`Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ServiceStackTest.Hello' to 'ServiceStack.ServiceHost.IReturn<ServiceStackTest.HelloResponse>'`

How on earth do they manage it here: 
[link](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C%23-client)

Comment: Does your route have any variables specified?  Can you show me the route you have?

Comment: Yeah:
Routes
    .Add<Hello>("/hello")
    .Add<Hello>("/hello/{Name}");

Comment: Ok, I've figured it out. I forgot to add the inheritance for the Hello class: public class Hello : IReturn<HelloResponse>